# How to access the top element in heapq without deleting (popping) it python?

Tags: python, heapq

How to access the top element in heapq without deleting (popping) it python ?
I need only to check the element at the top of my heapq without popping it. How can I do that.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

From [docs python](https://docs.python.org/3/library/heapq.html), under [heapq.heappop definition](https://docs.python.org/3/library/heapq.html#heapq.heappop), it says:

**To access the smallest item without popping it, use heap[0]**.

It says smallest, because it is a min heap. So the item at the top will be the smallest one.

Illustration:

```
import heapq

pq = []

heapq.heappush(pq,5)
heapq.heappush(pq,3)
heapq.heappush(pq,1)
heapq.heappush(pq,2)
heapq.heappush(pq,4)

print("element at top = ",pq[0])
print("check the heapq : ", pq)
```

Result:

```
element at top =  1                                                                                        
check the heapq :  [1, 2, 3, 5, 4]
```